# Convert date-string to Date object

Tags: javascript, date, django-templates

I have two date-strings that want to convert to `Date` objects.

Here is my approach:

```
var d1 = "{{demand.event_mindate}}";
var d2 = "{{demand.event_maxdate}}";

var max_date = new Date(d1);
var min_date = new Date(d2);
```

Here is the output via my `alert()` call:

```
d1 -> 29 mars 2016
d2 -> 29 avril 2016
```

The problem is that conversion of `min_date` to Date object works, but does not work for `max_date`. I am getting an invalid Date after converting.

Could anyone assist me with this issue?

Comment: How are you binding `demand.event_mindate`? What does the input date-string look like?

Comment: That is Django Template Language. when i print ad1 and d2 i got  d1 printed but d2 i got invalid Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you test all French months, all but February, May, June, July, August, and December get parsed correctly. This is because the first THREE (3) characters are correctly-parsed for months that start with the same letters as their English equivalent. It is just by chance that the names are similar. Please see the table below.

---

The easiest way to approach this problem of parsing a date-string based on locale, would be to use a library such as [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/).

If you need to parse a date in another language, you can either include the required language, or you can include [all languages](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment-with-locales.js).

For the sake of brevity, I took you *so called "output"*, and used it as input. Until you clarify what your input looks like, the following should be enough to solve the issue.

```js
moment.locale('fr'); // Load French
var frenchMonths = ('janvier,février,mars,avril,mai,juin,' +
                    'juillet,août,septembre,octobre,novembre,décembre').split(',');

generateRows(document.getElementById('date-table'), frenchMonths.map(function(month) {
  return '29 ' + month + ' 2016'; // Format the month name into a valid date-string
}), function(dateString) {
    return [
      dateString,
      new Date(dateString),
      moment(dateString, 'DD MMMM YYYY').toDate()
    ];
});

function generateRows(table, data, fn) {
  return appendChildren(table, data.map(function() {
    return createRow(fn.apply(null, arguments))
  }));
}
function createRow(data) {
  return appendChildren(document.createElement('tr'), data.map(function(value) {
    return createCell(value);
  }));
}
function createCell(value) {
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  td.innerHTML = new String(value).substring(0, 34);
  if (value instanceof Date && !isValidDate(value)) td.className = 'invalid';
  return td;
}
function appendChildren(parent, nodes) {
  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) { parent.appendChild(nodes[i]); }
  return parent;
}
function isValidDate(date) {
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]') {
    return !isNaN(date.getTime()); // d.valueOf() could also work
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
table, tr, th, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: thin solid #000;
}
.invalid {
  color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/locale/fr.js"></script>

<table id="date-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th>Output - Date Casting</th>
      <th>Output - MomentJS Parse</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

If you need to learn about formatting for MomentJS, check out the [formatting guide](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

---

## Update

I believe that this is what [RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg) was talking about:

```js
var months = 'janvier,février,mars,avril,mai,juin,juillet,août,septembre,octobre,novembre,décembre'.split(',');
function parseDate(datestring, months, expression, matchFn) {
  return matchFn.apply(null, expression.exec(datestring).map(function(value) {
    return !isNaN(value) ? parseInt(value, 10) : value;
  }));
}

var date = parseDate('29 avril 2016', months, /(\d{1,2}) (\w+) (\d{4})/, function(dateString, day, month, year) {
  return new Date(year, months.indexOf(month), day);
});

document.body.innerHTML = date.toString();
```

Comment: thanx for your answer. but why d1 work and d2 not? d1 imonth is in french!

Comment: @user3232446: Could you give me the ***actual*** input for both `d1` ***and*** `d2`? I assume they are Python date objects/strings... I can only determine what could be wrong then.

Comment: D1 is: 29 mars 2016 and d2 is:  29 Avril 2016. What i cant understand why D1 works and d2 not!  Yes this is python

Comment: @user3232446: I updated my response. I noticed that the month names that start with the same three letters as their English equivalent get parsed correctly. The internal Date parsing engine must try to match the first three character before deciding whether the given month is valid.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. That was the problem!!  that works now thx lot

Comment: That seems like a huge amount of code to perform a fairly simple task. Parsing and validation of the date is 4 lines of code, without Moment.js.

Comment: That was just for explanstion. The Code is.big because He generate the Table with Javascript to Show me the difference. Can you Show me PLZ your 4 line Code?

Comment: @RobG: I added a bit of code at the end of my response which should satisfy your suggestion. All the code in the original submission was to generate the table and show WHY the dates worked for some and not others...